# Why paint is not working?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paint, paintcomponent

Why the paint method is not working in this way but works in the 2nd way?

First way:

```
public class Ex extends JFrame{

public static void main(String args[]){
    JFrame frame=new JFrame("Title");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawString("HEllo", 500, 500);
}
}
```

Second way: is working Why?

```
public class Ex extends JFrame{
{
    this.setTitle("Title");
    this.setSize(800, 600);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    new Ex();
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawString("HEllo", 500, 500);
}
}
```

Comment: See also [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I had to fix in this question. Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, **select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.**

Comment: `JFrame` is not an instance of `Ex`

Answer (score 3):

If:

```
JFrame frame=new JFrame("Title");
```

Instead read:

```
JFrame frame=new Ex(); // we want an Ex, not a JFrame!
frame.setTitle("Title");
```

It should work.

Answer (score 3):

As Ex class is extending JFrame and paint method is overriden in Ex Class. Your Instance is of Ex class, So it is calling paint method of Ex class when you go with way 2. Hence it is working.

When you go with way 1, Your reference and Instance both are of JFrame, Hence it will call paint method of super class (i.e JFrame). If you want this paint method  of Ex class to be called, Instance should be of that class only, child class in your case.

Try

```
JFrame frame=new Ex();
frame.setTitle("Title");
```

This will have reference of JFrame and Instance of Ex Class. So paint will be called and It will work perfectly fine.